# Stripe Elements Charges not associated to Rails5 Devise current_user - Stripe::InvalidRequestError in CheckoutsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I have Stripe integrated with [Stripe Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/stripe/versions/3.3.1) and I can successfully create charges and a Stripe user; I just can't get the two to have an association.  If I associate the `:source => params[:stripeToken]` the charge goes through, but if I associate it with my user model `:source => current_user.stripe_customer`, I get a `No such token: cus_BX2RXGoOVkpvhL error.`

Here are my request parameters when associating with my user model.

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/KI7rzkJsM2uXIynoZkWKa1L+kNgyVcw+UsqfPNOnLYO3t4vfL+R7Yb4XhonyhwTbqlyWTtgYjey71ZroSmoRA==",
 "charge"=>"2200",
 "stripeToken"=>"tok_1B9yneHbiQgBeZWGq78mXM2l",
 "card_brand"=>"Visa",
 "card_exp_month"=>"4",
 "card_exp_year"=>"2024",
 "card_last4"=>"4242"}
```

**views/donations/show.html.erb**

```
...
<%= link_to 'Confirm Donation', new_checkout_path(charge: @donation.amount), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
...
```

**views/checkouts/new.html.erb**

```
<section>
  <h1>Secure Payment</h1>
  <div class="pages-content">
    <% if current_user.card_last4? %>
        <%= form_tag checkout_path, id: 'existing-card' do %>
            <p>Pay with existing card:</p>
            <div><strong>Card on file:</strong>
              <%= current_user.card_brand %> (**** **** **** <%= current_user.card_last4 %>)
            </div>
            <div><strong>Expiration:</strong> <%= current_user.card_exp_month %> / <%= current_user.card_exp_year %></div>
            <p>or <%= link_to 'add a new card', '#', class: 'show-card-form' %></p>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :charge, params[:charge] %>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit Payment">
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_tag checkout_path, id: 'payment-form', style: (current_user.card_last4? ? 'display:none' : nil) do %>
        <div class="stripe-wrapper">
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="card-element">
              Enter Your Credit or Debit Card
            </label>
            <div id="card-element">
              <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
            </div>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :charge, params[:charge] %>
            <!-- Used to display Element errors -->
            <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
          </div>

          <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</section>
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def stripe_customer
    if stripe_id?
      Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_id)
    else
      stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: email)
      update(stripe_id: stripe_customer.id)
      stripe_customer
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this instead, if you're charging the Customer by ID:

```
:customer => current_user.stripe_customer
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once and i remember that it was because my partner was using a different [Publishable key] on Testing mode, So i gave him mine and it worked, I would like you to make sure that the user is already exists on stripe.

I hope this help you.